# Does $\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty (-\frac{1}{\ln(n)})^n $ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty  (-\frac{1}{\ln(n)})^n $

I have tried the integral test, comparison theorem, cauchy criterion, but have no progress.

Is there a way to solve this using the cauchy criterion or the integral test?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the alternating series test?

Comment: (Also, what did you try for the comparison theorem? This should fall _very_ quickly by comparison to the right series)

Comment: Actually, it would be straight-forward if you do a ratio test.

Comment: @Steven There is a negative integer, so the comparison theroem will not work

Comment: @umuko This series converges absolutely.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

In fact, the series is absolutely convergent.  Note for $n>2$, we have

$$\log(n)\ge \log(3)>1$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternating series test:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(\ln (n))^n}$. Let $a_n := \frac{1}{(\ln(n))^n}$

- Clearly $a_n$ is a decreasing sequence.
- It is also clear that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

So the conditions for the alternating series test are met, so the series converges.

Comment: That's a lot of work when the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: @MarkViola Of course, but when I posted, someone posted that method. I was just showing an alternative way to do it :)

Comment: @AustinMohr Updated without the comparisons :)

Comment: And your methodology is fine and quite powerful beyond this example.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the calculus instructor. My calc professor insisted that the conditional convergence is like a consolation price. One tries to go for absolute convergence first. Only if the absolute series diverged that one would consider the consolation price.